# Plain text not added to my element correctly

Tags: polymer

In the below I am expecting [[myText]] to have the value "Hello world." I set in my markup.

The icon is displaying as I expected, but the value for [[myText]] is ... well [[myText]] and not the String I think it will be. Any ideas?

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Practice</h1>
<xhome-item toggle-icon="polymer" my-text="Hello world."></xhome-item>
```

xhome-item.html

```
<dom-module id="xhome-item">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="xhome-item.css" />

  <template>
    [[myText]]        // HERE HERE WHY isn't this set??
    <paper-button>
      <iron-icon icon=[[toggleIcon]]></iron-icon>

    </paper-button>
  </template>

  <script src="xhome-item.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

xhome-item.js

```
Polymer({
  is: "xhome-item",
  properties: {
    toggleIcon: String,
    myText: String
  }
});
```

xhome-item.css

```
:host {
        display: inline-block;
      }

iron-icon {
            fill: rgba(11, 31, 249, 0.64);
            stroke: rgba(249, 11, 11, 0.89);
          }

:host([pressed]) iron-icon {
                             fill: rgba(249, 11, 11, 0.89);
                           }

paper-button {
  background: green;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IT's working here: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Gz8juMqbVK0FGsimUDP?p=preview)

```
<template>
    [[myText]]        // HERE it's OK
    <paper-button>
      <iron-icon icon=[[toggleIcon]]></iron-icon>

   </paper-button>
</template>
```

Seams the problem is not in the code. It's good practice to set online example, easier to understand the problem.

Edit:

check the console log, is there some errors?

check with [unregistered_custom_elements.bookmarklet.js](https://gist.github.com/ebidel/cea24a0c4fdcda8f8af2)

Comment: Wow... yeah I see that. It is definitely not working on my machine. Though with yours I don't see the paper-button element. Besides that... yeah I don't know why it's not working. I am running it with Rails.... but the one attribute is definitely coming in and setting the toggleIcon. myText is just somehow actually printing out [[myText]]. .erb anything to do with it?

Comment: Added some ideas in the my answer.